# Behaviour of a closure that captures a local variable of function that it was returned from, in C++

Tags: c++, stack, closures

I am bit a confused why the following functions `normal_get()` and `closure_get()` behave differently. Sure, one returns a closure and the other a reference to a local variable. But essentially the former return value (closure) when invoked, does the same thing i.e returns a reference to a local variable of the function that it was returned from.

I am no c++ expert and I know one cannot a return a reference to a local variable within a function. But I would like to confirm whether it is an undefined or expected behavior for the closure scenario and there is no compiler magic there? (asking since I have recently started playing around with closures in C++)

I am using g++ 9.3.0

`g++ -std=c++2a test.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


auto closure_get() {
        int val = 10;

        auto f = [&]() {       // capturing by reference
                return &val;
        };

        return f;
}

auto normal_get() {
        int val = 10;

        return &val;
}


int main () {
        auto func = closure_get();
        auto val = normal_get();

        std::cout<<*func()<<std::endl;  // This always prints `10`. Should this be considered as undefined behavior though?
        std::cout<<*val<<std::endl;     // This always segfaults as expected. It's still undefined behavior even if it prints some value.
}
```

Comment: All of your code has undefined behavior.  Whatever results you get are "correct".  You cannot return a pointer/reference to a non-static function local object, as they are destroyed when the function ends.

Comment: Yes, I know. The one that segfaults or even if it returns some garbage or the local value is still an undefined behavior.  I just wanted to confirm the other scenario, the one that's returning a closure, as that seems to never segfault / or print garbage value.

Comment: Appearing to work is part of Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Yes, Just wanted to rule out any compiler magic there.

Comment: Your closure contains a reference to a value, not a copy of the value. The reference is stale as soon as the function ends.

Comment: Have you transcribed the code from the book properly? Is `val` really a variable local to the function and not a class member variable or similar?

Comment: There are no classes used here. It's all the code you see.

Comment: @vikram2784 Then your instinct to question it was good. Hopefully the book explains that both have UB - or it's a crappy book. Edit: I don't know why I say "book" all the time. It felt like it came from a book.

Comment: In both cases you are derferencing a value as if it's a pointer. The reason why *func() doesn't segfault is probably that it's (essentially) a function pointer, so derefing it might not do anything

Answer (score 3):

In both cases it is undefined behavior as any non-static local variable cannot be returned as reference or pointer as it is destroyed after the end of the scope of that function. So that reference or pointer will be invalid.